# 2sxc: Linq Count how many posts per tag

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I would like to implement an automatic tagcloud, so I need to have a list of distinct tags with the count of blog posts per tag.

Basically using the structure of the 2sxc Blog posts

```
"Posts": [
{
  "Title": "xxx",
  "KeyURL": "xxx",.......
  "Tags": [
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "Title": "A"
    },
    {
      "Id": 2,
      "Title": "B"
    },....
  ]
},
{
  "Title": "yyy",
  "KeyURL": "yyy",.......
  "Tags": [
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "Title": "A"
    },....
  ]
}
]
```

I can get all posts with the following code

```
var posts = AsDynamic(Data["Posts"]);
```

Then I tried to get all tags and the count for each but I cant get where I'm wrong.

```
var result = postsToShow.SelectMany(x => x.Tags)
               .GroupBy(x => x)
               .Select(x => new
                          {
                              Tag = x.Key,
                              PostCount = x.Count()
                         });
```

All I would like to get is a list

```
Tagname: A Count 2
Tagname: B Count 1
```

Comment: Your code looks mostly ok. What are you getting? That would help to suggest what should be changed. Do you get an error (then probably you need to cast something) or is it a wrong number?

Comment: Basically when I tried to read in a foreach I was having an error saying that Tag or  PostCount name there werent in collection.
I gave up and just counted how many tags there are in total per type and not grouped by posts